# Adding summary statistics to an existing table in SQL

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to add summary statistics (just total and average) to a table with 21 columns and 7 rows of data, I would like the two rows of summary statistics to start at row 8. I've been trying a query along these lines without any luck:

```
SELECT   *
FROM
    ( SELECT 1,
           weekday, summer_member_total, summer_member_avg_duration, summer_casual_total, summer_casual_avg_duration,
           fall_member_total, fall_member_avg_duration, fall_casual_total, fall_casual_avg_duration, 
           winter_member_total, winter_member_avg_duration, winter_casual_total, winter_casual_avg_duration,
           spring_member_total, spring_member_avg_duration, spring_casual_total, spring_casual_avg_duration,
           member_total, member_avg_duration, casual_total, casual_avg_duration,
    FROM `case-study-319921.2020_2021_Trip_Data.2020_2021_Summary_Stats` 
    UNION ALL    
    SELECT 8,
                'TOTAL',
                SUM(summer_member_total),
                SUM(summer_member_avg_duration),
                SUM(summer_casual_total),
                SUM(summer_casual_avg_duration),
                SUM(fall_member_total),
                SUM(fall_member_avg_duration),
                SUM(fall_casual_total),
                SUM(fall_casual_avg_duration),
                SUM(winter_member_total),
                SUM(winter_member_avg_duration),
                SUM(winter_casual_total),
                SUM(winter_casual_avg_duration),
                SUM(spring_member_total),
                SUM(spring_member_avg_duration),
                SUM(spring_casual_total),
                SUM(spring_casual_avg_duration),
                SUM(member_total),
                SUM(member_avg_duration),
                SUM(casual_total),
                SUM(casual_avg_duration),    
    FROM `case-study-319921.2020_2021_Trip_Data.2020_2021_Summary_Stats` 
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9,
                'AVG',
                AVG(summer_member_total),
                AVG(summer_member_avg_duration),
                AVG(summer_casual_total),
                AVG(summer_casual_avg_duration),
                AVG(fall_member_total),
                AVG(fall_member_avg_duration),
                AVG(fall_casual_total),
                AVG(fall_casual_avg_duration),
                AVG(winter_member_total),
                AVG(winter_member_avg_duration),
                AVG(winter_casual_total),
                AVG(winter_casual_avg_duration),
                AVG(spring_member_total),
                AVG(spring_member_avg_duration),
                AVG(spring_casual_total),
                AVG(spring_casual_avg_duration),
                AVG(member_total),
                AVG(member_avg_duration),
                AVG(casual_total),
                AVG(casual_avg_duration),    
    FROM `case-study-319921.2020_2021_Trip_Data.2020_2021_Summary_Stats` ) 
    ORDER BY 1
```

Any ideas on how to approach this?

Comment: what exactly the problem with what you tried? please clarify

Comment: Error Message:Column 2 in UNION ALL has incompatible types: INT64, STRING, STRING at [11:5]

Comment: provide example of first 3 columns in your table - but obviously it is about data types - so should be easy to fix

Comment: most likely weekday is INT64 while 'Total' and 'AVR' are strings - so fix either weekday to be string  or ... - that simple!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option to six your issue  - replace

```
SELECT 1,
           weekday, summer_
```

with

```
SELECT 1,
           CAST(weekday AS STRING) weekday , summer_
```